# Order of Entire function, Shifted

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Let $f$ be an entire function, and $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that order of $f(z+a)$ is equal to the order of $f(z)$.

My attempt:

> Denote $g(z)=f(z+a)$. I tried to take bounds for $f$ and $g$ in the form of $$\Large e^{r^{\text{order} \pm \epsilon}}$$ over circles around $z=0$ that are big enough to cover smaller circles around $z=a$ (the definitions of order all go over circles aroung the origin). But I'm stuck this way, as the radiuses are different, and comparing the values of $f$ and $g$ on circles with different radiuses doesn't imply different or equal order.

Comment: Compare the formula for a circle around the origin, with the formula for a circle around $a$ that encloses and is tangent to the circle around $0$. Use the maximum modulus theorem to bound the maximum modulus on the smaller circle by the maximum on the larger circle. Do the same exchanging the roles of $0$ and $a$. Finally use that $\frac{\ln(r\pm|a|)}{\ln(r)}\to1$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: @cactus thank you, this helped me to solve. If you post this as an answer I would accept.

Comment: You can post yours and accept it too.